# Can't find app on Google Play but can see it from URL

Tags: android, google-play

I published an app yesterday and see it when I type https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename into my browser. It's clearly on the play store, yet I cannot find it when I search the store from my phone or my computer. I was able to download it onto my phone using the URL above. Is there a setting I'm not selecting or something that would be causing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Play can be notoriously slow, both for the Developer Console and the Front End for users.

I've seen apps go live and not turn up on my Developer page or in search results for close to 48 hours. There is no way you did anything wrong, as Google Play doesn't provide any option for you to omit apps from your search results which you may have accidentally enabled.

I'd recommend waiting for a day or two more. If it still doesn't turn up, you could try contacting Google Play support, but I wouldn't get my hopes high about even receiving a response.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response, that's what I figured...I'll just give it some more time.

Comment: Did yours eventually show up - if so how long did it take? Seems I'm having the same issue (direct link works, search doesn't).

Comment: Didn't work - my app can not be found for two months but is available with url

Comment: Same here. If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Also, how can Google Play support be contacted?

Comment: same problem here, its almost 10 days spent but still I can't search my app by name, even I show all the play store apps and goes upto extreme end but No way. And searching by package name, it shows the App quickly. And thats the reason that there is very nil downloads of my App. See
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clipinapps.birdsoundsandroid

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clipinapps.animalsoundsandroid

Apologizes for free publicity, but just wana show you that you please search it by name or other keyword, you wouldn't find it. How to get this. plz